# Continue button not working for Luis Portal

Tags: azure-language-understanding

[image]

I have logged in with my MSDN account and i have owner rights, i have also checked that i am using the right directory.

Comment: Hi, we have received several reports regarding accessing LUIS portal. We are investigating internally and will get back to you once we have more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a faulty change in our deployment that caused this error while accepting the terms of use from all LUIS portals. A hotfix is now rolled out and this issue is now fixed.